# Bloomberg Excel formula result length limits

Tags: excel, excel-formula, bloomberg

I am using the Bloomberg excel add-in to retrieve security names from Bloomberg symbols. I've noticed that the result is limited to 30 characters. This is insufficient length for many names. Here's an example:

=BDP("MERCPA2 LX Equity", "SECURITY NAME")

This returns "BlackRock Global Funds - US Do" which is about a third of the answer I expected. Is there a way to modify the formula so that it returns the entire valid security name?

Comment: This would be more of a question for the folks who made the add-in.  Are you able to see the code behind it? Maybe you can tweak it there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few fields available. In your case you can try `LONG_COMP_NAME` which will give longer results.

You can also try `NAME` which may be helpful.

Comment: The `LONG_COMP_NAME` field worked perfectly. Thanks for the suggestion.